# Maximum value with condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 =4$ and $x_i \ge -1$ I have to prove that

$I=(x_1^2+3)(x_2^2+3)(x_3^2+3)(x_4^2+3) \le 256.$ Since

$ I \le (\frac {x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 +12}{4})^4 $

then I have to find the maximum value of $ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 .$ Since

$ (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 +2 x_1 (x_2 + x_3 + x_4) +2 x_4 (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)$

I have that

$ x_2^2 + x_3^2 + 16 = (4 – x_1)^2 + (4 – x_4)^2 .$

So, I have to prove that

$(2 – x_1)^2 + (2 – x_4)^2 \le 2$

and here I stuck. Thank you

Comment: If $x_1 = 7$ and $x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = -1$, then $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 4$ and $x_i \ge -1$ for every $i$.  Yet, $I = (7^2 + 3)\cdot( (-1)^2+3)\cdot( (-1)^2+3)\cdot( (-1)^2+3) = 52\cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 > 256...$.  Did you mistyped anything ?

Comment: Maybe, I'll check it, but my question still remains

Comment: If the statement is wrong, we cannot truly help you.